# Can I split index.php with forms in several files?

Tags: php, forms

I'm starting with php (but I was quite experienced on C++) and I have some questions. The thing is that I would like to have several forms in the index.php, and to have the code more clean I would like to call functions to call the forms.

Right now, I'm having the running code as teh follow:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Prueba de PHP</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 
 <form id="nomfromnum" action="getCharName.php" method="GET">
    <input type="number" min="1" name="charidbox" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Seleccionar personaje">
</form>

 <form id="despPers" method="POST">
    <select name="nomChar">
    <?php
    
    include("conection.php");
    
    $con=conectar();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Personajes";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo '<option value="'.$row["Character_id"].'">'.$row["Character_name"].'</option>';
      }  
    ?>
    </select><br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

In the first form, I was able to move it into another file (getCharName.php). But for the second function (despPers), that creates a dropdown menu and populates it with its values, I wan't able to find the way to move it to another file. I tried to chance the header for  and create a file despPers.php with the following code but it didn't worked.

```
    <select name="nomChar">
 <?php
 
    function despChar($conexion){
    
    
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Personajes";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo '<option value="'.$row["Character_id"].'">'.$row["Character_name"].'</option>';
      }  
    }
    
    include("conection.php");
    
    $con=conectar();
    
    despChar($con);
    $con->close(); 
    
 ?>
    </select><br>
```

Can anybody guide me with this? Maybe it's something basic, but I'm quite freshman on php and html.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Might want to turn on error reporting/display. On the line `$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);` in your function ... `$con` is no longer your connection variable, the parameter from your function is named `$conexion`

Comment: Thanks! Too many copy paste. It's working now.

Comment: You're welcome, glad it works

Answer (score 0):

Oops, it was a wrong variable name.
Anyway, here you have what I have done.
On the index.php

```
<form id="despPers" action="despChar.php" method="POST">
    <select name="nomChar">
    <?php    
    include("despChar.php");    
    despChar();    
    ?>
    </select><br>
</form>
```

And the despChar.php is

```
 <?php 
    function despChar(){ 
    
        include("conection.php");    
        echo '<option value="0">Character</option>';
        $con=conectar(); 
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM Personajes";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
          echo '<option value="'.$row["Character_id"].'">'.$row["Character_name"].'</option>';
        }  
     
        $con->close();    
    } 
 ?>
```